# Function lookup table with different function prototypes

Tags: c, function-pointers, function-prototypes

What is the best way to call a specified function based on user input except from series of `if` and `strcmp`?

For example:

```
p 2 2 -> call func_p(2, 2)
a 8   -> call func_a(7)
m     -> call func_m(void)
```

I know it's easy and elegant to make a lookup table consisting of function pointers with the same prototype but how about different prototypes? I thought about using `...` in a prototype but I don't know if it's a good solution.

Comment: Define all the functions so they take a single array argument.

Comment: It's my second thought - make all functions accept `char *` and call a specified function based on the first word on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Define all the functions so they take a single array argument.
>
> Comment from Barmar

Unifying all functions to the same prototype is exactly what one normally does in this case, though I'd go with a prototype with two parameters: A pointer to an array with the real parameters as well as it's size. That way not every function has to split/parse its arguments on its own.

I really like stuff like this, so I made a short demo. I made this on my mobile, so it's a bit rough and would need some improvements if used in the wild (memory management and error detection for example). Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

// a node in the abstract syntax tree. Either a
// value or a call
struct Ast {
  bool isCall;
  union {
    int value;
    struct {
      char const * operator;
      size_t countOperands;
      struct Ast * operands;
    } call;
  };
};

// unified function type. Could've also passed an
// int array, but then evaluate would've needed
// a memory allocation, so ...
typedef int (*Function)(struct Ast *, size_t);


// implementation of + function. Sums the values of
// parameters. (which are hopefully evaluated)
int sum(struct Ast * parameters, size_t num) {
  int result = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
    --num;
    result += parameters [num]. value;
  }
  return result;
}

// implementation of ? function, ignores any
// parameters and just asks for an integer.
int ask (struct Ast * parameters, size_t num) {
  int value;
  scanf("%d", & value);
  return value;
}

// poor man's lookup table
static Function const functions [] = {sum, ask};
static char const * const function_names [] = {"+", "?"};

// poor man's lookup from above static arrays
Function lookup (char const * name) {
  size_t it = sizeof (functions) / sizeof (functions [0]);
  while (it > 0) {
    --it;
    if (strcmp(name, function_names [it]) == 0) {
      return functions [it];
    }
  }
  exit(1);
}

// evaluate an Ast. Normally one wouldn't return
// an Ast node but rather some value_t (assuming
// dynamic typing)
// this function is also destructive on call Ast nodes,
// in order to get around any memory management.
// so be careful!
struct Ast * evaluate (struct Ast * node) {
  if (! node->isCall) {
    // anything that's not a call is a value, thus
    // self evaluating, return it unchanged!
    return node;
  }
  // so it's a call. Get the associated function from
  // the lookup table!
  Function f = lookup(node->call.operator);
  // unconditionally evaluate all operands of the call.
  // thus no macros or conditionals, sorry!
  size_t o;
  for (o = 0; o < node->call.countOperands; ++o) {
    // destructive!
    node->call.operands[o] = *evaluate(&(node->call.operands[o]));
  }
  // use the call node to store the result value.
  // this will blow up if any call node uses any
  // allocated memory!
  node->isCall = false;
  // call the function with the evaluated operands and
  // store the result
  node->value = f(node->call.operands, node->call.countOperands);
  return node;
}

int main () {
  // I didn't want to write a parser, so here's a
  // static Ast of (+ 21 10 (?))
  struct Ast nodes [] = {
    {.isCall=false, .value=21},
    {.isCall=false, .value=10},
    {.isCall=true, .call = {
        .operator="?", .countOperands=0}},
    {.isCall=true, .call = {
        .operator="+", .countOperands=3,
        .operands=nodes}}};
  struct Ast * result = evaluate(&(nodes [3]));
  printf("(+ 21 10 (?)) => %d\n", result->value);
  return 0;
}
```

[Written and "tested" on ideone.](http://ideone.com/yawecz)

A different approach would be to use a `void *`  tagged with some function type information. But it's rather difficult to pass the actual parameters to functions encoded like that, and it also doesn't scale well.