# What do you do in C++ if you ask for an integer and the user inputs "b"?

Tags: c++, string, input, static

I'm new to statically typed C++.  In JavaScript, I could just check the data type first, but that seems to be very [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834810/how-to-check-data-type-in-c), and the answers all seem to imply that you aren't "getting" the language.

here's the code I was testing out rand() with, where I came upon the issue of converting strings to integers:

```
int main(){
std::string input;
    cout <<endl<< "What to do?"<<endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "rand")
    {
        cout << "what is the max?" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        int number;
        if (stoi(input) > 1) {
            number = stoi(input);
        }
        else {
            number = 10;
            cout << "using 10"<<endl;
        }
        cout << rand() % stoi(input);
        return main();
    }
}
```

so in Javascript, I would just check the type of input or result, but what do people do in C++?

Not allowed to say thank you in the comments so I'm saying thank you here!

Comment: Don't check the type of the input (it will be a string anyway), check if it's value can be casted to a valid integer by `stoi`. Solutions to this are proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c).

Comment: The question is not about `std::atoi` (which does not perform any checking), but about `std::stoi` (and in extension `std::strtoi`).

Comment: In part the issue is what do you consider to be a valid number? `stoi` has it's own definition and as already stated it throws an exception if that isn't met. If `stoi` doesn't do what you want then just perform you own tests on `input`, use a regex perhaps.

Comment: In two spots you set `number`, but it is never used.  Probably should only call `stoi(input)` once, and use that to set `number`, and then use number after that spot in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to the [documentation of std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) it throws an `std::invalid_argument`.

What you could do is to place your `std::stoi` call inside a `try` and then catch the `std::invalid_argument`, but personally i wouldn't do that.

Instead, it is (most likely) a lot better to check if the first character of your input is an `int`, because if it is one, it can simply be parsed by `std::stoi`.

You can do that by e.g. doing the following:

```cpp
int max = 0;
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;

if(std::isdigit(input[0]))
  max = std::stoi(input);
```

EDIT: Please note that this would not respect the case of a too big number, to handle that case you would need an additional check.

Comment: This may still throw an exception if your input is larger than the maximum integer value. It will also pass values such as "42chickens".

Comment: @gha.st yes, fair point with the integer overflow, you could add an extra check for that. For the case with '42chicken' i would actually want to parse the 42 out of there as it is up to the user to input the correct number (as it is requested). so those attempts are usually tests to try and get a program to misbehave, which wouldn't be the case here.

Comment: This answer is the easiest for me to understand, and I wasn't aware of isdigit, which seems intuitive to me.  I can imagine making a simple function to check if the input is fully a number or contains non-number characters.

Comment: @sheepdeets please be aware that as gha.st mentioned, this is not handling the case of a potential integer overflow. you'd need an additional check for it.

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's try out what happens: https://godbolt.org/z/1zahbW

As you can see, [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) throws an exception if you pass it invalid input or its input is out of range.

You should, however, be aware that `std::cin >> some_string;` is somewhat non-obvious in that it reads in the first "word", not a line or anything like that, and that `std::stoi` does the same thing (again).

One way to perform the check, could be like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Please give me a number: " << std::flush;

    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    try {
        auto value = std::stoi(input);
        std::cout << "Thanks for the " << value << " (but the string was \"" << input << "\")\n";
    } catch(std::invalid_argument const&) {
        std::cout << "The provided value is not an integer\n";
    } catch(std::out_of_range const&) {
        std::cout << "The provided value is out of range\n";
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rKrv8G

Note that this will parse `"   42 xyz"` as `42`. If that is a problem for your use case, you may wish to use [`std::strtoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) directly, or to check if your input is valid before parsing (e.g., using a [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex))